# Get response from array

Tags: php, while-loop

I write:

```
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
            global $user_id;
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // fetching all user tasks
            $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["tasks"] = array();

            // looping through result and preparing tasks array
            $response["error"] = false;
                $response["id"] = $result["id"];
                $response["task"] = $result["task"];
                $response["status"] = $result["status"];
                $response["createdAt"] = $result["created_at"];
                echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

but with this code I get only first result [0] ...

```
{
error: false
tasks: [0]
id: 2
task: "Create something"
status: 0
createdAt: "2014-12-01 01:58:42"
}
```

How to make while loop on results to get all data from results?

Comment: What framework are you using ?

Comment: You're not looping anything. And you should pass in $user_id instead of using global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $row){
echo $row["id"];
 //-- and so on
}
```